# Camel - Why the file consumer move option working differently with pollEnrich?

Tags: apache-camel

When I use a file consumer

```
<from uri="file:in?move=$simple{file:name}-transfered&amp;include=^demo_keys\.ks$&amp;sortBy=file:name" />
```

the file(s) are renamed to xxx-transfered (as I expected and stated in the doc) after processing.

But when I use the same with pollEnrich (for just one file)

```
<pollEnrich>
<simple>file://in?fileName=demo_keys.ks2&amp;move=${camelId}-uploaded&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;delay=8000</simple>
</pollEnrich>
```

the file is not renamed after processing, instead moved into a newly created sub-directory with the original name.

How can I rename the pollEnrich processed file, achieve the same behaviour as a normal file consume?

I've tested it with v2.17.2 and v2.18.0
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a bug in Camel; try using a file language expression (e.g. `${file:name}`) instead of `${camelId}` just to be sure but [the official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html#File2-MoveandDeleteoperations) is pretty much clear in this case - it should interpret the value as a file name instead of directory.

I guess you should report a bug in Camel's JIRA.

Comment: Thanks. I've it tested with several expressions like file:name, which is empty in that case (it's weird as well) that why I used something which has value... I try to report it, you can be right.

Comment: I think this is a bug, I have seen this before as well.